# Blender to Zbrush problem

Tags: mesh, zbrush

When importing my .obj from Blender to Zbrush it looks off. I've tried exporting it as a .fbx with no luck, and different kinds of subdiv levels.
I'm not sure what info is relevant, so please ask, but it looks like this. [image]

Comment: Hi. Modifiers stack and export options could be relevant.

Comment: Thanks! I've used a mirror modifier, tried both with and without applying it. I also tried to export it as .obj both with and without joining all meshes together, and not really changed anything when exporting as .obj.

Comment: Do you have many ngons? If yes, have you set triangulate option in obj export?

Comment: triangulate fixed the problem, thank you!